# Format the y-axis label in the higher thousands with many zeros to scientific notation?

Tags: python, matplotlib, format, axis, scientific-notation

How can I tighten the y-axis by using scientific notation?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y=np.array([1,1,1,2,10,2,1,1,1,1])*100000
ax.plot(x, y)
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotting with scientific axis, changing the number of significant figures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34992685/plotting-with-scientific-axis-changing-the-number-of-significant-figures).  This question has been asked and has an answer.  You should add your answer to that question if you think it's sufficiently different from the existing answers.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.
I was looking quite a while for this question but could not find it.
I was searching for keywords like "y-axis label" "higher thousands" and "many zeros".  
Probably this second question might help people to get the answer easier accessible.

Answer (score 0):

With `plt.ticklabel_format`:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y=np.array([1,1,1,2,10,2,1,1,1,1])*100000
ax.plot(x, y)
plt.ticklabel_format(axis="y", style="sci", scilimits=(0,5))
plt.show()
```

[image]